# How send ZPL to Zebra with Google Cloud Print?

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, google-cloud-print

Does anyone have an idea how to send via Google Cloud Print - ZPL string to the printer?
Sending in print job - GCP converts it to pdf and simply prints the text.
I can't find anything on the internet. Some threads are but no answer.
Is it possible to use the "proxy" of the printer that is in Google Cloud Print?
I tried http://labelary.com/service.html and converting ZPL to PDF via API, but such labels are terrible and this is not a solution. On my computer, the "Generic text" setting in the printer enables printing a txt file with ZPL and then it's ok, but how to use it in Google Cloud Print?

Comment: Is google cloud print the requirement or do you just need print via cloud?

Comment: Google Cloud Print is the requirement :/

Comment: FYI: Cloud Print is being discontinued. https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9633006